# The debug parameter is deprecated. Python logging library errors out when executing

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, logging, error-logging

I'm using the "logging" library in a script that runs in python3.6 but when i execute it i gives me below error:

> The debug parameter is deprecated. If you want to enable debug-level
>   logging, make the appropriate setting in the logging subsystem:
>   logging.getLogger('bender.config.service.ConfigProvider').setLevel(logging.DEBUG).
>   To get rid of this warning, don't pass a debug parameter

- im not passing any debug parameters in the script, just a few infos and warnings.
- tried `logging.getLogger('bender.config.service.ConfigProvider').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` , same result.

Comment: Can you please add logging initialization and config file (if any) so we can see them?